# QGIS 3.4.0 Madeira: unresponsive

Tags: qgis-3, performance

I "upgraded" from 3.2.3 to 3.4.0 and it's so unresponsive it's unusable. The startup time is the same as 3.2.3, then it needs half a minute to build its UI.

When I click on the UI, the reaction is the same as if the computer is under 100% load; the task manager however does not report any spikes. After another half minute of being the active window, the UI is responsive (can be dragged, smooth zoom, hovering over the top context menu pops up the dropdowns, etc.) until something is done that makes the window lose focus again, e. g. dragging a file from the explorer, or clicking on a layer to access its properties window. Is anyone else experiencing this problem? Version 3.2.3 runs buttery smooth.

// edit:

I'm running Windows 10, 3.1 GHz hexacore, 16 GB RAM, 8GB video card. As suggested below, I tried reinstalling, as well as the --noplugins flag. Neither led to any improvement.

Comment: I am running QGIS 3.4 on Windows 10 and I don't have the same issue. In fact mine is fast and the response is quick. I am not sure if you are using windows or not because you did not specify your OS. Try to uninstall completely QGIS from your machine and reinstall it again. Maybe something wrong happened during the installation.

Comment: You could try disabling all plugins and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: In my experience, the first release of a new version (ie x.x.0) of QGIS is usually extremely buggy. I usually wait until at least x.x.2 before installing a new version. You can help with the bug-fixing process by reporting this bug at www.issues.qgis.org.